# How to overwrite integer at specific part of text file?

Tags: java, file, overwrite

I have a textfile called "BookDetails.txt"

It is formatted in Book Title, Author, Publisher, Branch Call Number, and # of Copies like so:

> 1984 : George Orwell : Penguin : FIC Orw : 23

In my program, I am trying to overwrite the number of copies from 23 to 22 (decrementing by one essentially) when a patron checks out the specific book

```
public class CheckOutDialog extends javax.swing.JDialog {
private static final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
ArrayList<CheckOut> checkOuts = new ArrayList<CheckOut>();
String bookTitle; 
int numberOfCopies;
/** 
 * Creates new form CheckOutDialog
 */
public CheckOutDialog(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
    super(parent, modal);
    initComponents();
    Date currentDate = new Date();
    jTextFieldDate.setText(df.format(currentDate));
}


private void jButtonCheckOutActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
    String firstName = jTextFieldFirstName.getText();
    String lastName = jTextFieldLastName.getText();
    bookTitle = jTextFieldBookTitle.getText();
    String checkOutDate = jTextFieldDate.getText();

    CheckOut checkOutInfo = new CheckOut(firstName, lastName, bookTitle, checkOutDate);

    checkOuts.add(checkOutInfo);

    CheckOutCopy();
}                                               

public void CheckOutCopy() //This method checks for book and num of copies
{
     try {
        File f = new File("BookDetails.txt");
        Scanner fileRead = new Scanner(f);

        boolean foundTitle = false;
        fileRead.nextLine();
        while(fileRead.hasNextLine())
        {
            String textLine = fileRead.nextLine();
            String[] bookInfo = textLine.split(" : ");
            String tempBookTitle = bookInfo[0];
            numberOfCopies = Integer.parseInt(bookInfo[4]);


            if(tempBookTitle.trim().equals(bookTitle))
            {
                foundTitle = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(foundTitle && numberOfCopies > 0)
        { 
           OverwriteCopies();
           WriteCheckOut();
           this.setVisible(false);
        }
            else if(numberOfCopies == 0)
            {
                if(JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to add the patron to the queue?", "No copies available", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                {
                    AddPatronQueue();
                }
                else
                {
                    JOptionPane.getRootFrame().dispose();
                }
            }
        else
        {
            JOptionPanes.messageBox("Book was not found in Library Catalog", "Check Out Error");
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

 private void OverwriteCopies()
{
    numberOfCopies--;

    //Unsure how to proceed from here
}


private void WriteCheckOut()
{
    WriteFile wf = new WriteFile("CheckOutDetails.txt");

    for(int i = 0; i < checkOuts.size(); i++)
    {
        CheckOut c = checkOuts.get(i);

        String checkOutDetails =  c.getFirstName() + " : " + c.getLastName() + " : " + c.getBookTitle() + " : " + c.getCheckOutDate();

        wf.write(checkOutDetails);
    }
    wf.close();
}
```

My program is successful in finding a specific book and its number of copies (and it produces the JOptionPane if it has 0 copies left). However, I am unsure of how I can overwrite and update that specific element within the text file. I have done some research and it seems that RandomAccessFile may be one possible option. Is the RAF the viable solution to my problem or is there another option that I can take?

Comment: How big wil l be your books file? If it is small, you can manipulate the data in an ArrayList of strings and re-write whole contents to the file

Comment: There's not a safe way to do this unless your text file uses fixed-length records, which doesn't seem to be the case. Otherwise, your only option is to rewrite the entire file.

Comment: @HariPrasad Although the user will be able to continuously add books to the text file, for testing purposes I will probably only have 5 books in the text file

Comment: @chrylis Could you direct me to some resources on how I could implement that option?

Comment: As @Hari mentioned, you'll basically have to read in the entire file into a list of `CheckOut` instances and then write it back out again to save it. You'd probably want to go with the model that you typically see where you "open" the file once, read it in, work with in-memory contents, then finally "save", instead of your current attempt to hit the file on every UI operation.

Comment: @Hari I understand how I can read the entire text file into a String arraylist. However, I am a bit confused on how I can manipulate the data in the arraylist.

Comment: In the ArrayList each element will be one line from your file. Whichever line you want to modify, split that line on ":" and you will get each fields of the line in String Array. Now it is in your hand to modify whichever the value you want, join the fields back and replace the line in the ArrayList. Finally you can write back the contents to file

Comment: I see you have already have the CheckOut class. You can utilize the same class by adding the numberOfCopies as a member. Then you can also add a toString() function which will get you the String representation of your data in the format which you write to file. Then it will be easy to manipulate

Comment: @Hari Thank you. Would this process be similar to how I found the numberOfCopies in my CheckOutCopy() method?

Comment: Yes. However for this kind of data manipulation it would be better to store the data in a DB. If you want to continue to use storing in file, I suggest, read the contents of the file into ArrayList<CheckOut> and do the manipulation in the list. It would be easier.